# Trigger github actions workflow (e2e tests)/call api when spring boot application is ready in kubernetes using hook

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, github-actions, argocd

I'm trying to find a way how to trigger a github actions workflow or just call an api once the java spring boot application is ready to work (bootstrapped) which runs on kubernetes cluster in order to run e2e tests.

I have tried to use a postsync hook of argocd with a sleep:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: api-test-trigger
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: BeforeHookCreation, HookSucceeded
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: api-test
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 100000
        runAsGroup: 100000
        fsGroup: 100000
      containers:
        - name: api-test
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
          env:
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - "sleep 5 && curl -X POST -H \"Accept: application/vnd.github+json\" -H \"Authorization: Bearer xxxxx\" https://api.github.com/repos/xxxx/xxxx/actions/workflows/run.yml/dispatches -d '{\"ref\":\"main\"}'"
          image: curlimages/curl
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Never
```

The api is called after the pod/container is in "Running" state, which does not mean that the application within the pods is ready to work. I could of course set the sleep to e.g. 1 minute hoping that this work out all the time but I don't think this is an ideal solution.

An other idea would be to use the lifecycle of the container:

```
      lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sh
                      - -ec
                      - "sleep 5 && curl -X POST -H \"Accept: application/vnd.github+json\" -H \"Authorization: Bearer xxxxx\" https://api.github.com/repos/xxxx/xxxx/actions/workflows/run.yml/dispatches -d '{\"ref\":\"main\"}'"
```

Which sould lead to the same result as above with posthook.

I was hopping to find a solution which would e.g. trigger the github api once the readinessProbe of the application is returning valid values.

I'm open for any solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to start e2e tests againsts the application which runs in the cluster

Comment: Why don't you run the e2e tests as part of a cluster in the pipeline?

Comment: What do you mean as a part of a cluster? In the github workflow pipeline?

Comment: Yes, starting a cluster as part of the build.

Comment: My problem is not to start the cluster since the cluster runs all the time on azure. If I deploy a new version of a application it takes time until the java spring boot application is available and I want start the tests against the new version and not the one which runs before. To achieve this I need somethink like a hook which tells me: you app is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I would use f.e. testcontainers.org or k3s to bootstrap a lightweight cluster to run the e2e tests and a) not rely on external resources and b) avoid concurrency issues.

If you want to query if your application is ready use a readiness probe, which can be combined with a  headless service configured with `publishNotReadyAddresses` set to true.